# AWS: How to add tensorflow modules from EFS to Lambda function dependencies?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, keras, aws-lambda

I'm trying to deploy my machine learning model to AWS Lambda function. I trained my model locally with Keras and got .h5 file.

I zipped Tensorflow and Keras modules and added it to EFS mounted on EC2 instance. Then, i successfully added the EFS to the file system of Lambda function.

```
print("EFS Directory :",os.listdir("/mnt/efs"))

EFS Directory : ['utils.py', 'model.py', 'parallel_model.py', 'm_rcnn.py', 'mask_rcnn_object_0008.h5', 'python2.zip']
```

(python2.zip is a zip folder of Tensorflow and Keras modules)

The last step is to load my model with `keras.models.load_model()` to load my .h5 model and predict the result. The issue is that i can't import the dependencies from python2.zip.

Firstly, i tried

```
sys.path.insert(0, "/mnt/efs/python2.zip")
from python2.keras.models import load_model
```

I got

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "No module named 'python2'",
  "errorType": "ModuleNotFoundError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 49, in lambda_handler\n    from python2.keras.models import load_model\n"
  ]
}
```

Then, I used the tool `zipimport.zipimporter.find_module()` to find the path to keras.model at `'python2/tensorflow-1.13.1.data/purelib/tensorflow/python/keras/models'` but it return `'None'`

Does anyone have ideas how to add `keras.models` from `python2.zip` in EFS to the Lambda function path? My goal is just to use `load_model` and `predict` function from Keras.

Thank you

EDIT

I used `pip3 install tensorflow-cpu` in EC2 cli which seems to work since i didn't get an error when open python3 editor and `import tensorflow` in EC2 cli.

```
pip3 show tensorflow-cpu

Name: tensorflow-cpu
Version: 2.8.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: six, google-pasta, tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, protobuf, termcolor, libclang, numpy, flatbuffers, tf-estimator-nightly, gast, typing-extensions, keras-preprocessing, h5py, astunparse, opt-einsum, grpcio, keras, absl-py, tensorboard, setuptools, wrapt
Required-by:
```

However, i still unable to add that tensorflow dependencies to Lambda function.

Comment: I have never tried loading from EC2 before but what is the directory structure in your zip file?  I have created lambda layers with torch and they must have a directory structure in the zip file that starts with python.  So python/torch/various files.

Comment: @RodP Inside python2.zip are 'tensorflow-1.13.1.data' and 'tensorflow-1.13.1.dist-info'. I got them by downloading the tensorflow-gpu in whl format then unzipped using wheel. The  path of the module is 'python2/tensorflow-1.13.1.data/purelib/tensorflow/python/keras/models'

Comment: @RodP Anyway, does the Torch require Tensorflow dependencies? Firstly, i also tried adding Keras modules to the Lambda layer too but i got an error about Keras requiring Tensorflow dependencies which is bigger than Lambda limited size at 512Mb.

Comment: I was simply using torch because that is what I downloaded but replace torch with tensor and use the same folder structure.  See this layers page.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html.  Place the folders that you downloaded from the wheel into a python folder within your zip file, and see if that changes the outcome.

Comment: I know you are not using layers but perhaps it needs the same folder structure.  Lambda size is a big challenge for the machine learning files.  It took a lot for me to get the torch files into a layer but before you go down that route see if you can get your EC2 working by simply changing the directory structure in your zip file.